# Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "NLog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"

Tags: docker

Ставлю Docker for Windows на Win 10, 64, получаю ошибку:

Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "NLog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Найденное определение манифеста сборки не соответствует ссылке на сборку. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Как исправить?